# How to show full content of a remote url in a Twitter Bootstrap Modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I need to show full content of an remote URL in a modal when I click on a button. I search Google and Stackoverflow for my solution I find very questions like this but no answer work correctly.

for example I want to see Google.com in a full width Modal

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

```
<a role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal">Open</a>

<div id="modal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    Test Modal
   </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <iframe src = "http://www.yahoo.com"></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also check this link - http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: Feel free to accept this answer if you think its working for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Put an iframe in the modal. For example:

```
<div class = "modal">
<iframe src = "google.com"></iframe>
</div>
```